# Why is my UTC instant not converting to BST?

Tags: java-time, threetenbp, threetenabp

I have the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.UK);
Instant inst = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(sdf.parse("2019-08-13T18:00:00Z"));
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm").withLocale(Locale.UK).withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
System.out.println(formatter.format(inst));
//prints 18:00
```

This is surprising to me as I thought `inst` would be a GMT/UTC time and the `formatter` would format it to London time (which is BST (UTC+1:00) for this date), producing `19:00`.

What am I missing here?

I'm guessing this is a generic issue with my code, but if it makes a difference this is using the `org.threeten.bp.*` classes from the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, further adapted for early Android in the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

Comment: I added a mention of [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) which I assume you are using for early Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Instant                                    // Represent a moment in UTC.
.parse(                                    // Generate a `Instant` object from the content of text input.
    "2019-08-13T18:00:00Z"                 // String in standard ISO 8601 format.
)                                          // Returns a `Instant` object.
.atZone(                                   // Adjust from UTC to the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone). 
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" )           // Specify a time zone using name in proper `Continent/Region` format. Never use 2-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `BST`.
)                                          // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toLocalTime()                             // Extract the time-of-day, without a date and without a time zone or offset. Returns a `LocalTime` object.
.format(                                   // Generate text representing the content of this `LocalTime` object. 
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedTime ( FormatStyle.SHORT ) // Automatically localize while generating a `String`.
    .withLocale ( Locale.UK )              // Locale determines the human language and cultural norms to use in localizing.
)                                          // Returns a `String` object.
```

> 19:00

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Your are mixing the terrible legacy classes (`SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`) with the modern *java.time* classes. Don’t do that. Use only *java.time*.

## `Instant` = moment in UTC

Skip your first two lines of code. Your input string `"2019-08-13T18:00:00Z"` is in standard ISO 8601 format. These standard formats are used by default by the *java.time* classes when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "2019-08-13T18:00:00Z" ;
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2019-08-13T18:00:00Z

## `Instant` is not flexible

I suspect your problem was in your attempt to format the value within a `Instant`. The `Instant` class is a basic building-block class within *java.time*. It merely represents a moment in UTC. It is not intended for things such as flexible generation of strings.

The more flexible classes are `OffsetDateTime` & `ZonedDateTime` classes.

## `ZonedDateTime`

Apply a `ZoneId` to your `Instant` to adjust into a time zone, rendering a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2019-08-13T19:00+01:00[Europe/London]

You seem to want to focus on the time-of-day alone. Extract a `LocalTime` object.

```
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime ();
```

> lt.toString(): 19:00

For the London region in Daylight Saving Time (DST) on that date, the offset-from-UTC is one hour ahead. So we see the time-of-day is 7 PM versus the 6 PM of UTC.

## Proper time zone

By the way `BST` is not a time zone. I suggest you avoid using these pseudo-zones.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `BST` or `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
```

## Use smart objects, not dumb strings

Your example code suggests you are too focused on strings. Use smart objects, not dumb strings.

Get your objects straight, using appropriate types. Generating strings should be the last step, a side-effort, akin to localization. Your business logic should be done by using proper objects, not by manipulating strings.

## Localization

And speaking of localization:

```
Locale locale = Locale.UK;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime ( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale ( locale );
String output = lt.format ( f );
```

> 19:00:00

Switch the locale to `Locale.US` for a different kind of result:

> 7:00:00 PM

---

All the code above was run in Java 13 early-access with the [*ThreeTen-Backport*](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) library per your needs stated in the Question.

```
import org.threeten.bp.* ;
import org.threeten.bp.format.* ;
```

Note to the reader: The *ThreeTen-Backport* library is further adapted for early Android in the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP in Android*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706). If using Android 26 and later, the *java.time* classes are bundled, so you do not need the back-port at all.